# Problems understanding definition of \newif

Tags: conditionals, plain-tex

Reading http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf, I have come across the definition of `\newif` on page 75:

```
\def\newif#1{\@ifdefinable{#1}{\@newif#1}}
\def\@newif#1{\count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\def\@if#1{true}{\let#1=\iftrue}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\def\@if#1{false}{\let#1=\iffalse}%
\@if#1{false}\escapechar\count@} % the condition starts out false
\def\@if#1#2{\csname\expandafter\if@\string#1#2\endcsname}
{\uccode‘1=‘i \uccode‘2=‘f \uppercase{\gdef\if@12{}}} % ‘if’ required
```

I'm trying to understand how it works by following its expansion. So imagine I type `\newif\iffoo`.

1. The first expansion should be

   ```
   \@ifdefinable{\iffoo}{\@newif\iffoo}
   ```

   therefore checking if there is an already defined `\iffoo` and then, if there is none, passing `\iffoo` to `\@newif`. And that's where my problems begin.
2. `\@newif` should expand into:

   ```
   \count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \def\@if\iffoo{true}{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \def\@if\iffoo{false}{\let\iffoo=\iffalse}%
   \@if\iffoo{false}\escapechar\count@
   ```

   Now `\count@` is a counter (`\countdef\count@=255`) and so is `\m@ne` (`\countdef\m@ne=22 \m@ne=-1`), and `\escapechar` contains the code point of `\`, being defined as `\escapechar=\\` (I can't put the backtick after the `=` because the site's markup causes trouble). So `\count@\escapechar`, I guess, gives `\count@` that code, and `\escapechar\m@ne` makes `\escapechar` `-1`. That's for later, in `\if@`. Then we have the sequence of `\expandafter`s. Now the first one makes TeX skip the second one, and see the third one, which makes it skip `\def` and expand `\@if`, which we will get to later; then TeX (I guess) remembers it had skipped through an `\expandafter`, go back to it and execute it; this means `\def<expansion of \@if\iffoo{true}>{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}` is delayed, and we enter a new sequence of `\expandafter`s; the first one is skipped and stored away due to the left-over `\expandafter` which delayed the just-mentioned `\def`; so the second one is executed, the third one consequently stored away, and so we get a `\def` executed which should redefine `\if@` but that can't be! So the definition of the expansion of `\@if\iffoo{true}` as `\let\iffoo=\iftrue` takes place before the second `\expandafter` of the first sequence is executed, but why? Well in that assumption we get to expanding the second `\@if` and defining its expansion as `\let\iffoo=\iffalse`, then we have one/two `\expandafter`s; if there are two, they should elide, making me wonder why bother putting three both times if one both times is sufficient, whereas if there is one we get `\count@` and then `\escapechar`, so we have a useless instruction which is the repetition of one at the beginning, `\count@\escapechar`. So there must be two, right? And eliding, right? So why bother putting three?
3. And now the `\@if`. We have, as said above:

   ```
   \@if\iffoo{true}
   ```

   so the expansion should be:

   ```
   \csname\expandafter\if@\string\iffootrue\endcsname
   ```

   The `\expandafter` leaves `\if@` as it is, and expands the `\string`, which makes `\iffootrue` become `iffootrue`, since `\escapechar` is `-1<0`; so we get to:

   ```
   \csname\if@iffootrue\endcsname
   ```

   right?
4. Finally, the line `{\uccode‘1=‘i \uccode‘2=‘f \uppercase{\gdef\if@12{}}}` makes `i` the uppercase of `1` and `f` the uppercase of `2`, probably to make sure `\if@` in the `\uppercase` doesn't get taken for `\if@if`, since we're in `\makeatletter`, but split off because `1` and `2` cannot be put in a control sequence and are then turned into `i` and `f` by `\uppercase`. So here's the `\if@`: it gets expanded to `{}`, leaving just:

   ```
   \csname footrue \endcsname
   ```

   (or `foofalse`). So we understand the actual reason of the `\expandafter` in the `\csname…\endcsname`: to delay the expansion of the `\if@`, which is global since it's `\gdef`, so is defined in a group to leave the `\uccode`s local but is set to global to be used back up in those `\csname…\endcsname`s.
5. Finally, of course, we want `\escapechar` back to its original value, which was stored in `\count@`, and is restored at the end of everything.

After all these reflections, I seem to have been left with only one question mark: why three `\expandafters` per `\if@` control sequence definition? So the question finally is:

Is there anything wrong in what I have said, what is it, and why are there those three `\expandafter`s up there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\def\@if\iffoo{true}{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}%
```

recalling the definition of `\@if`:

```
\def\@if#1#2{\csname\expandafter\if@\string#1#2\endcsname}
```

The first `\expandafter` expands the third one, which in turn causes the expansion of `\@if`, which has two arguments; in this case they are

```
#1<-\iffoo
#2<-true
```

where I use the customary way TeX uses for showing what argument are assigned. So we're left with

```
\expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\if@\string\iffoo true\endcsname
```

Now the remaining `\expandafter` triggers the expansion of `\csname` that, I recall, does exhaustive expansion until finding the matching `\endcsname`. So, in order to know what control sequence name will be produced, we have to follow the expansion of all tokens after `\csname`.

The first token is `\expandafter`, that causes the expansion of `\string`; since `\escapechar` is -1, we're left with

```
\if@ iffootrue\endcsname
```

Because of its definition, `\if@` removes `i` and `f` and leaves `footrue`; so we have

```
\def\footrue{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}
```

It's now the same procedure for defining `\foofalse`.

The definition of `\if@` is indirect, because it must be followed by `i` and `f` of category code 12, for all character tokens produced by `\string` have category code 12 (except spaces).

You're wrong in thinking that TeX remembers having expanded `\expandafter`: this token just disappears after triggering the expansion of the second token after it. Also it's incorrect to say that two of them elide each other.

---

Note 1: in a couple of places there's an apparent space, where there isn't really one; it's just for distinguishing one token from another. Notably there is one in `\string\iffoo true` and one in `\if@ iffootrue`.

Note 2: this is *not* the definition of `\newif` in the LaTeX kernel, where a simplified version is used, which doesn't check if the control sequence after `\newif` has a name starting with `if` (as discussed in the book when `\newif` is described).

---

Just for fun, here's how one could implement `\newif` in `expl3`. Of course this is only an exercise to show that one can get “clearer” programming.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xnewif}{ m }
 {
  \xnewif_newif:N #1
 }

\tl_new:N \l__xnewif_name_tl

\msg_new:nnnn { xnewif } { bad~input }
 { #2 }
 { The~argument~\token_to_str:N #1 is~#2;~fix~it }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \xnewif_newif:N #1
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
   {% the control sequence is already defined, stop
    \msg_error:nnnn { xnewif } { bad~input } { #1 } { already~defined }
   }
   {% the control sequence is undefined, go on
    \__xnewif_newif_do:N #1
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xnewif_newif_do:N #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__xnewif_name_tl { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnNTF { \A if } { } \l__xnewif_name_tl
   {% the name of the control sequence starts with `if', go on
    \cs_gset_eq:NN #1 \if_false: % start globally false
    \cs_new:cpn { \l__xnewif_name_tl true } % define \if...true
     {
      \cs_set_eq:NN #1 \if_true:
     }
    \cs_new:cpn { \l__xnewif_name_tl false } % define \if...false
     {
      \cs_set_eq:NN #1 \if_false:
     }
   }
   {% the name of the control sequence doesn't start with `if', stop
    \msg_error:nnnn { xnewif } { bad~input } { #1 } { not~starting~with~`if' }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Test
\xnewif\iffoo
\show\iffoo
\footrue
\show\iffoo
\foofalse
\show\iffoo

\xnewif\isss
\xnewif\iffoo
```

Here's the output on the terminal

```
> \iffoo=\iffalse.
l.50 \show\iffoo

? 
> \iffoo=\iftrue.
l.52 \show\iffoo

? 
> \iffoo=\iffalse.
l.54 \show\iffoo

? 

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! xnewif error: "bad input"
! 
! not starting with `if'
! 
! See the xnewif documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.56 \xnewif\isss

? 

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! xnewif error: "bad input"
! 
! already defined
! 
! See the xnewif documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.57 \xnewif\iffoo
```

Comment: I like how the word “clearer” is in quotation marks ;)