# Why in the discussion of the definition of \newif are the following things true

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

This is a couple of questions that stem from the answer to [Problems understanding definition of \newif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171672/problems-understanding-definition-of-newif) by [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

In that @egreg says

> Let's look at
>       `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter`
>       `\def\@if\iffoo{true}{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}%`
>   recalling the definition of `\@if`:
>       `\def\@if#1#2{\csname\expandafter\if@\string#1#2\endcsname}`
>   The first `\expandafter` expands the third one, which in turn causes the expansion of `\@if`, which has two arguments; in this case they are
>       `#1<-\iffoo`
>       `#2<-true`

But from my understanding the way that `\def` works is that it is sensitive to the non-argument characters (i.e., characters other than `#1`,`#2`,…,`#9`) that follow the command's name, such that (to take from p202 of the TeXbook) if you have `\def\cs #1. #2\par{…}` then `\cs` will need arguments that are given in the format `#1. #2` where you need a `.␣` separating the two, such that

```
\cs You owe \$5.00. Pay it.\par
```

gives

```
#1 <- You owe \$5.00 
#2 <- Pay it.
```

Where (to quote the TeXbook)

> the period in \5.00 doesn't stop `#1`, because TeX keeps going until finding a period that is immediately followed by a space.

And in the above `\def\@if#1#2` is not `\def\@if#1{#2}`, and I would imagine that the latter wouldn't work since it would interpret `#2` as the definition of `\@if#1` thinking that `\@if` only took a single argument `#1`.

My second difficulty was in understanding the following section

> So we're left with
>       `\expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\if@\string\iffoo true\endcsname`
>   Now the remaining `\expandafter` triggers the expansion of `\csname` that, I recall, does exhaustive expansion until finding the matching `\endcsname`. So, in order to know what control sequence name will be produced, we have to follow the expansion of all tokens after `\csname`.
>   The first token is `\expandafter`, that causes the expansion of `\string`; since `\escapechar` is `-1`, we're left with
>       `\if@ iffootrue\endcsname`

But I do not understand why `\string` has that effect both in the situation where `\escapechar=-1` or where `\escapechar` has not been reassigned.

Acc. to the TeXbook

> `\string<token>` TeX first reads the `<token>` without expansion. If a control sequence token appears, its `\string` expansion consists of the control sequence name (including `\escapechar` as an escape character, if the control sequence isn't simply an active character).

So I'm left to surmise that if it replaced `\` before `iffoo` in `\iffoo` then

1. why does `\string` have that effect when `\iffoo` is a control sequence and so (acc. to my likely misunderstanding of the TeXbook) should just be turned into its name, which is `\iffoo` (or is it `iffoo`, in which case why did the `\escapechar` need to be changed). Or,
2. If `\` was replaced as it is a "control sequence token" as opposed to a "control sequence", per se, where did the `-1` go?

And finally, in the next section @egreg says

> Because of its definition, `\if@` removes `i` and `f` and leaves `footrue`; so we have
>   `\def\footrue{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}`

I believe that `\if@` is defined in the following:

```
{\uccode‘1=‘i \uccode‘2=‘f \uppercase{\gdef\if@12{}}} % ‘if’ required
```

And I understand that the first part sets the uppercase value of `1` to be `i` and `2` to be `f`, but i do not understand why this section is enclosed in a separate set of brackets nor why this definition acts to remove `i` and `f` since it would seem to either be undefined if `\uppercase` was applied initially since `\GDEF` is not a valid command or would be expecting `1` and `2` as fixed arguments (not `i` and `f`) that it would eliminate (in that it returns an empty string).

I apologize if this seems entirely esoteric, but I am really trying to understand why these definitions work as they do, and I genuinely don't know where I'm going awry. I had originally intended to ask this in the comments of the original answer, but @egreg helpfully pointed out that my questions were extensive enough that comments were an inappropriate place for that discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saying `\newif\iffoo` generates the following list of tokens:

```
\count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\@if\iffoo{true}{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\@if\iffoo{false}{\let\iffoo=\iffalse}
\@if\iffoo{false}
\escapechar\count@
```

In what follows, spaces (or newlines) are added just for separating tokens; there is none in the definitions, so none is generated.

I recall also the definition of the auxiliary macros `\@if`

```
\def\@if#1#2{\csname\expandafter\if@\string#1#2\endcsname}
```

and `\if@`

```
{\uccode‘1=‘i \uccode‘2=‘f \uppercase{\gdef\if@12{}}} % ‘if’ required
```

### What does `\if@` do?

TeX opens a group, where new `\uccode` values for `1` and `2` are set. Then it executes `\uppercase`. The operation transforms *character tokens* in their uppercase equivalents, without changing category codes. The resulting token list is put back in the input stream and it is

```
\gdef\if@ if{}
```

where `i` and `f` have category code 12 (like `1` and `2`). The space is there just for clarity, there's no space token. So the macro `\if@` wants to see after it that pair of character tokens or an error is issued and swallows them producing nothing. Next the `}` restores the `\uccode` values of `i` and `f`.

### Step 1

The assignments `\count@\escapechar` and `\escapechar\m@ne` are performed. In particular, the escapechar is set to –1, which means that `\string\cs` will expand to `cs` (each character with category code 12), because –1 is not a valid character code.

### Step 2

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\@if\iffoo{true}{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}
```

TeX jumps over a token and expands the next one, which is `\expandafter`, so another token is jumped over and the next is expanded. It is `\@if`, which takes two arguments. The macro is not followed by `{`, so the first argument is the following (non space) token, which is `\iffoo`; a `{` follows, so the second argument is all tokens up to and including the matching `}`, so `{true}`. Recall that TeX strips off a pair of braces from an undelimited argument (and also from a delimited one, if this doesn't leave unbalanced braces). So argument `#2` is `true`. Substitute `\if@\iffoo{true}` with the replacement text

```
\csname\expandafter\if@\string\iffoo true\endcsname
```

Again, the space is not there, I leave it just for separating tokens. There are ten tokens in this token list.

### Step 3

Two `\expandafter`'s are gone, the replacement text has been put in place of `\if@` and its arguments, so we have

```
\expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\if@\string\iffoo true\endcsname{\let\iffoo=\iftrue}
```

TeX jumps over `\def` and expands `\csname`. This will ultimately expand to a symbolic token, that's in turn built up by expanding whatever comes up to the matching `\endcsname`

### Step 4

Let's look what's the token list up to `\endcsname`:

```
\expandafter\if@\string\iffoo true
```

(the space is not there, remember). TeX jumps over `\if@` and expands `\string`. This produces the five character tokens `iffoo` (because `\escapechar` is –1) all with category code 12. Thus we're left with

```
\if@ iffootrue
```

and `\if@` is expanded. The required tokens are found and swallowed, so we get `footrue`. Now TeX finalizes the `\csname...\endcsname` construction, producing the token `\footrue`.

### Step 5

The input stream has

```
\def\footrue{\let\iffoo\iftrue}
```

that's executed and removed.

### Step 6

TeX now finds

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\@if\iffoo{false}{\let\iffoo=\iffalse}
```

and does exactly the same as before, but the final token list is

```
\def\foofalse{\let\iffoo\iffalse}
```

that's executed and removed.

### Step 7

Now we have

```
\@if\iffoo{false}
```

that does the same as before, producing just

```
\let\iffoo\iffalse
```

so the conditional starts out false.

### Step 8

The final tokens

```
\escapechar\count@
```

reset `\escapechar` to the value it had before starting `\newif\iffoo`.

Comment: Step 2 was absolutely crucial. Did not know that the brackets would just be swallowed in that way and that what might be thought of as the output of the command sequence is delimited with `{}` and that arguments that are expected can also use `{}` to group characters to input as that argument. In Step **4**, is the `\ ` at the front of `footrue` due to the way that `\csname` works since it is meant to produce a valid control sequence as its output? And in steps **1** and **8**, `count@` is just acting as a holding register for whatever `charcode` `\escapechar` has before running the code.

Comment: @mpacer in step 4 there isn't a `\ ` in the expansion of `\csname` it is the single token with name `footrue` which is conventionally written as `\footrue` but it is  not 8 tokens starting `\ ` it is 1.

Comment: @mpacer You need to remember that while we tend to write `\foo` it means 'the control sequence `foo`': the escape char is needed as part of the input but isn't part of the name. Try setting `\escapechar` to something else to see this, for example: ``\def\foo{Definition}\def\firstofone#1{#1}\begingroup\firstofone{\escapechar`\a\show\foo\endgroup}\bye`` and see what the log shows!

Answer (score 10):

working backwards:

```
{\uccode‘1=‘i \uccode‘2=‘f \uppercase{\gdef\if@12{}}} % ‘if’ required
```

`\uppercase` works on tokens and any token other than a character token is left unchanged. Character tokens produce new character tokens with the same catcode as before but with character code obtained by looking up the uccode (if that is non zero)

so `\gdef` uppercases to `\gdef` not to `\GDEF` and you get

```
\gdef\if@ if{}
```

which defines `\if@` to take no argument and expand to nothing but gobble a catcode 12 i and f (or generate an error).

It's like this:

```
\catcode`i=12
\catcode`f=12
\def\if@if{}
```

except that doesn't work as the `f` in `\def` needs to be catcode 11 and as do the `i` and `f` in `\if@`

the construct is enclosed in brackets as you do not want the uppercase of 1 to be i for the rest of the document.

I'm not sure I understand your `\string` question. `\string\iffoo` makes the sequence of catcode 12 tokens `\` `i` `f` `f` `o` `o`  except that the first `\` is whatever character is specified by `\escapechar` or nothing if that is not a legal character code, so as it is `-1` here `\string\iffoo` produces `iffoo`.

Comment: I apologize if this is me just being dense, but why isn't \gdef equivalent to the catcode 0 token `\ ` followed by catcode 11 tokens `g` `d` `e` `f`? and so `\uppercase`, when it applies to those character tokens, why does it not transform those character tokens to `G` `D` `E` `F`? 

And the gobbling you describe I think is what I meant by `i` and `f` being fixed arguments, but I'm still confused.
Normally you are using `\newif` to pass a command with catcode 11 tokens(letters), how does it know to treat the catcode 11 tokens passed into it as valid catcode 12 tokens to be gobbled up?

Comment: @mpacer `\gdef` is _one token_ a command token with name `gdef`  the argument to `\newif` isn't catcode 11 letters it is again a single token such as `\ifwibble`  `\string` takes a token and _always_ makes a sequence of catcode 12 tokens (or catcode 10 in case of space), so `\ifwibble` is one token `\string\wibble` expands (if escapechar is -1) to 6 catcode 12 character tokens

Comment: Oi. Where in the TeXbook is this explained? I thought i'd read this stuff pretty thoroughly, which is why I thought that `\string` would treat `\foo` as a single token, but then it didn't make sense that it could treat the `\ ` separately. And the definition of \string doesn't say anything about it changing it into catcode 12 tokens, so I'm not sure where that's established… And just to make sure I understand, setting `\escapechar` to `-1` makes its `\charcode` not within the 0-255 valid codes, and it doesn't modularize it to make `-1 → 255`?

Comment: Just found page 40 in the TeXbook… "Each character in this token list automatically gets category code 12("other"). Including the backslash that `\string` inserts to represent an escape character." And `\string` looks for what to represent the escape character as and then the nonexistence of `\charcode` of `\m@ne`(or -1) in the tables means that it treats it as an ignored character (or catcode 9, <null>). Can't find a reference for that last bit, but I think that fits…

Comment: @mpacer it doesn't make a catcode 9 character it simply makes nothing (sometimes tex-the-program is more informative than the texbook:-=)

Answer (score 4):

The Knuth's macro `\newif` is very cryptic. I spent full page 402 in my "[TeXbook naruby](http://petr.olsak.net/tbn.html)" with explanation of this. But we can ask if there isn't more straightforward and more understandable solution of this task with equivalent result. I mean that it exists. For example:

```
\def\newif#1{\expandafter\newifA\string#1\relax#1}
\edef\tmp{\string\if}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\newifA\tmp#1\relax#2{%
   \newifB#2{\csname#1true\endcsname}{\csname#1false\endcsname}%
}
\def\newifB#1#2#3{% #1=\iffoo  #2=\footrue  #3=\foofalse
   \let#1=\iffalse
   \expandafter\def#2{\let#1=\iftrue}%
   \expandafter\def#3{\let#1=\iffalse}%
}
```

Comment: While I'd agree Knuth's definition is odd, I'm not sure this answers the question in hand (it would be fine for 'Is there a simpler alternative to Knuth's definition of `\newif`?' for example). Perhaps ask a separate question and answer it yourself?

Comment: I did mean (from the name of this thread) that it is the "discussion about `\newif`" and my answer is new point to such discussion. I see that debaters are drown in the problem of cryptic macro and that they are unable to see the problem from another point of view. My answer shows that the Knuth's macros is not good educational material about macro programming. Many pieces of TeX macro code (especially from LaTeX) are very cryptic with redundant code and this makes (unfortunately) TeX as less favourable for many users.

Comment: This fails if `\escapechar` is not 92 at the time of the `\newif`.

Comment: There is also a simpler implementation of newif in latex.

Comment: LaTeX allows to use `\newif\foo` without error message which defines `\otrue` and `\ofalse`. It is not full optimal.

Comment: @egreg The `\escapechar` changing are typically done for local purposes, but `\newif` is declarator (the original `\newif` is declared as `\outer`). This is the reason why I didn't solve this minor case in my macro. If somebody needs to use `\newif` when `\escapechar` isn't 92 then (s)he knows what to do.